# Mouse turning itself on and off

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, mouse

Microsoft mouse keeps turning on and off, and now i got error code 43 and it just turned off completely.

I have a regular Microsoft 3-Button usb wired optical mouse. Recently it has started turning on and off, and now it gets error code 43 in the device manager. If I disconnect and reconnect it, it seems to work for a while then starts to turn on and off again and eventually gets error code 43 and turns off completely.

I have tried to connect the mouse to other usb ports, and it happens in them all. Tried reinstalling and updating the usb and the mouse drivers.

The strange thing is, when I connect that same mouse to a laptop, it looks like it works fine, no errors or nothing.

UPDATE: ended up buying a new (exact same) mouse, and it worked. Must have had something in the old one.

Comment: Code 43 is a hard one - Do you have problems with any other USB device?

Comment: Right now it seems all other USB devices have no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310123), the error code 43 in the device manager stands for an error, which was reported by the device. Microsoft advices to take a look into the hardware documentation.

Those device errors are reported by the corresponding drivers. Do you use the same drivers on both computers? Maybe its really just a driver issue. How did you un- and reinstall them?

Comment: On both computers I just use the default Microsoft drivers. And when I uninstalled it, I just let it reinstall the default drivers back.

Comment: Do you use the same version of Windows on both machines? Maybe one of them has different drivers. 

It's unlikely that Microsoft will offer an additional driver for this mouse, that cannot be found in Windows / via Windows Update, but you might want to take a look if such a driver exists. If so, try this driver instead of the standard one.

Otherwise I have no idea, how you could solve this issue.

Comment: Both machines have win 7 on them and both had the windows update drivers installed on them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a couple of years back, and the way I solved it was a BIOS firmware upgrade. EXTREMELY dangerous to perform for the inexperienced, but if you trust yourself it may be worth looking in to.